# Difference between 'nun' and 'nunmehr'

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the difference between them? I see many 'nunmehr' when it seems to me that 'nun' is also okay.

Comment: Do you have an example or some context?

Comment: The second doesn't even look very German to me. :-) The sentences containing "nun" I interpret without it. I do the same with a similarly unclear meaning "doch". German is tricky... :-) and wonderful.

Answer (score 4):

Typically *nun* refers to **a moment in time**, which can be both in the past or in the future. For example:  *Was ist nun geschehen?* *Was machen wir nun?*

*Nunmehr* on the other hand refers to **a period of time**, which can also be in the past (specifying a number for the amount of time) or in the future (open ended). For example: *Seit nunmehr zwei Wochen regnet es.* *Wir wollen uns nunmehr vertragen.*

But I agree there is some overlap and in some cases *nun* might be used in place of *nunmehr* (but not the other way around).

There are some other uses of *nun*:

- to start a question: *Nun, was ist Ihre Entscheidung?*
- to continue an item in a list: *Nun kommen wir zum zweiten Punkt auf der Tagesordnung.*
- as a fill word to gain time when thinking about something: *Nun... du hast Recht.*

Comment: yes, but when used referring to the future it is more an (infinite) outlook than a (limited) period of time.

Comment: @Philm: Agreed, and updated in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The use of *nunmehr* is quite rare and a bit oldfashioned, but can be a fine tuning- a means to stress something. You can use *nun* nearly always instead of *nunmehr* (without that emphasis). In the following there is only one sentence, you cannot.

In many cases, *nunmehr* could be let away completely without that the sentence would get grammatically incorrect or a changed meaning, because it is only an emphasis- it stresses something.

The two most common meanings are:

**First- usage- in a context to a past time period, which shall be stressed:**
Because of that, mostly an explicit period of time is mentioned as with *since* or *for*:

(for [more than] 30 years)

> Seit [nunmehr] [über] 30 Jahren sind wir verheiratet.

(for the past 12 years)

> Seit [nunmehr] 12 Jahren...

(since)

> [Nunmehr] seit 1992 existiert unsere Firma.

(only sentence here where it can´t be replaced by *nun*.)

**Second- usage as a future lookout:**
A merely **infinite** prospect/lookout in the future where it can have a meaning of *from now on* as well as *meanwhile* (Infinite in the sense that it is the opposite to a time period.)

> Nunmehr bleibt ihm keine Alternative.
>   Nunmehr kostet das Ticket 6 EUR.

Dictionaries seem to mention more meanings. In other contexts than mentioned I would judge it's use questionable in modern German, for example, if it can be used as a general substitution of *jetzt* without context to the past (1.) or the future (2.) .

(now)

> Wir können [nunmehr] aufatmen.

(Correct and does not reference a time period, but has in fact implicit associations both to (fear in the) past and future relief.)

> Kommen wir [nunmehr/nun] zum zweiten Punkt der Tagesordnung.

(There is probably a small emphasis, hint or a subtext here, when using *nunmehr*. For example, the first topic took too long, the speaker wants simply to be very formal, or to give a hint to speed up a bit, maybe accompanied with facial expressions.)